# The NVIDIA driver creates multiple FUSE devices and intensively loads up the system

Tags: drivers, nvidia, fuse, proprietary-drivers, flatpak

When I boot up my arch distro, sometimes (75% of the time) it starts creating FUSE devices and load up my system, so that I cannot use it, unless I reboot and then everything seems normal. It can create up to 20 FUSE devices all with the same name. The name of FUSE devices is like "NVIDIA flatpack cache". What is this? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/flathub/org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia/issues/42

Comment: That's not Nvidia, that's the flatpak runtime creating the fuse mounts; it's how flatpak works.